# Microsoft Graph API for mail using $value issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to export Exchange email (on premise) into *.eml file. The API

```
GET　https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/{id}/$value
```

seems is the appropriate one. But it returns error below.

405 Method Not Allowed

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidRequest",
        "message": "The OData request is not supported. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-02-19T15:22:01",
            "request-id": "9118f0dd-8d06-4e2b-9fdb-355123ba6a66",
            "client-request-id": "78ed917d-4602-867a-5db4-6615e6c29696"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried the

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages/{id}/$value
```

but still got same error.

But the

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/{id}
```

can return result properly. It seems this is not security issue, because this API should already return enough data for constructing the *.eml file.

Any one have advise for this?

Answer (score 0):

From the error it sounds like maybe you have a Hybrid environment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support and your trying to export a Message from a Mailbox that is onPrem?. If so that won't work for the onPrem mailboxes because they can only do a limited subset of the graph operations and Mime Export isn't one of the current features (not sure if that is going to change in the future). The only work around I know for onPrem would be to use EWS for those mailboxes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange until this feature comes to the Graph for Hybrid mailboxes.